# jQuery results set keeping populating

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have jQuery function that makes an ajax call that builds a HTML string to populate the `<ul></ul>` feature.  the problem is there is link on the page that does a refresh of the page, the problem is that the HTML that got added the jQuery ajax call adds the HTML to the page again so that the result is not doubled.  if you do it again the result gets added again.

So my question is how can i clear the HTML so the result is repeated multiple times?  or what is the best way to solve this problem?

// Expand copy to group modal groups
            $(".groupZones .expand").live('click', function() {
                $(this).siblings('.contract').show();
                $(this).css('display', 'none');
                $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.groupDetails').css('display', 'block');
                $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.groupDetails').find('ul.device').find('ul .list').after('');
                var cwpUserId = $('#ctl00_cphBody_hfCwpId').val();
                var groupId = $(this).parent().siblings('.add').find('input').val();
                sortOn = "Location";
                var mode = "dayparts";
                var groupUl = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.groupDetails').find('ul').find('ul li.head');
                var groupDetails = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.groupDetails');
                //Get the zone details..
                // Load.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/DaypartMessagingGroups.asmx/GetDetailsForCopyToGroup",
                data: "{'groupId':" + groupId + ",'cwpUserId':" + cwpUserId + ",'pageNum':0,'pageSize':5, 'sortOn':'" + sortOn + "','sortDirection':'" + sortDirection + "','mode':'" + mode + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    //$(btn).parents("ul.list-group-zones").children("li:.head").after(msg.d);
                    $(groupUl).after(msg.d);
                    $('.location').find('.contract').hide();

                    var copyZonePerPage = 5;
                    //var copyZoneItemsCount = $(groupUl).siblings('#hfAllGroupZones').val();
                    var copyZoneItemsCount = $('#hfAllGroupZones').val();
                    var copyZonePages = Math.ceil(copyZoneItemsCount / copyZonePerPage);
                    var copyZoneHtml = '';
                    var copyZoneCurLink = 0;
                    var current_copyzone_pagination_set = 1;
                    var num_of_pagination_shown = 0;
                    alert('Line 2113 CBG');

                    if (copyZonePages > 20) {
                        //var pagesAdded = (parseInt(current_copyzone_pagination_set) - 1) * 10;

                        while (num_of_pagination_shown < 20) {
                            copyZoneHtml += '<a class="page_link_clicked" longdesc="' + copyZoneCurLink + '">' + (copyZoneCurLink + 1) + '</a>';
                            copyZoneCurLink++;
                            num_of_pagination_shown++;
                        }

                        copyZoneHtml += '<a class="page_link" id="btnNextZoneSet" longdesc="' + copyZoneCurLink + '">...</a>';

                    }
                    else {
                        while (copyZonePages > copyZoneCurLink) {
                            copyZoneHtml += '<a class="page_link_clicked" longdesc="' + copyZoneCurLink + '">' + (copyZoneCurLink + 1) + '</a>';
                            copyZoneCurLink++;
                        }
                    }

                    $(groupUl).parent().parent().find('ul li.footer').html(copyZoneHtml);
                    $('.page_link_clicked[longdesc=0]').addClass('current');

                },
                error: function(err) {
                    var err = eval("(" + err.responseText + ")");
                    if (ShowModalLogin(err.ExceptionType)) {
                        alert("An error occurred.");
                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you insert the content from the string, I'd ask the `<ul>` if it is empty.

```
var $ul = $('#myUL');

if( $ul.is(':empty') )
   $ul.append( content );
```

or a shorter version:

```
$('#myUL:empty').append(content);
```

- http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

Note that `:empty` means completely empty, including spaces.

---

**EDIT:**

If the page refreshing is an unneeded side effect of some other action, you can prevent it in your handler for those `<a>` elements using [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault).

```
$('a.myLink').click(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default behavior of the <a> element.
    // run your code
});
```

Comment: The OP mentions refreshing the page.  Think that means a data refresh?

Comment: @rchern - I thought of that too. It is not clear from the question. If that's the case, I would think it would be better to adopt a strategy that only retrieves new, unique data instead of the entire set in order to reduce bandwidth. Or at least track which items have been downloaded and only append the unique ones that were received in order to reduce DOM activity. Good point, though. :o)

Comment: I interpreted it as wanting to refresh the actual data in the ul.

Comment: @rchern - You may be right. The only thing that made me think otherwise is that OP refers to refreshing the entire page, which would seem to be un-AJAX like. I assumed there's some caching going on, and the refresh is coming from a different action. I could very well be wrong, though.

Comment: with some debugging and alert messages i see that the jquery is running one time. the web service is processing multiple times. to explain better is the page shows <ul> elements of information, that also have sub <ul> elements. the page looks like a form with sub forms. there is filter link on the top of the page that allows me to change the top level of data. When i click on the link that filters the page and the page already been filtered with that type of data the sub <ul> repeats the web serivce call multiple times, but only calls the jquery method once.

Comment: @C Green - Could you please edit your question to post the code where the request is being made? Any chance the request is being made in a loop? Or in the callback to an animation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the content you add is wrapped by a container (your `<ul>`), simply clear the contents of the container prior to adding the new content.

You can use the jQuery .remove() function to accomplish this.

Comment: with some debugging and alert messages i see that the jquery is running one time.  the web service is processing multiple times.

to explain better is the page shows <ul> elements of information, that also have sub <ul> elements.  the page looks like a form with sub forms.  there is filter link on the top of the page that allows me to change the top level of data.  When i click on the link that filters the page and the page already been filtered with that type of data the sub <ul> repeats the web serivce call multiple times, but only calls the jquery method once.